# Angularjs ng-hide animation not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I tried angularjs animation from [this plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/dvpdnjps/). But on my local, animation is not working. Normal hide/show is working but animation is not shown.

My code is al below:

**index-show.html**

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./app-show.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./app-show.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp1">
        <div id='outerdiv' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div ng-click="myValue=true">LEFT</div>
            <div ng-click="myValue=false">RIGHT</div>
            <div id="one" class='animate-hide' ng-hide="myValue">this is just a sample div</div>{{myValue}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app-show.css**

```
.animate-hide {
    -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    line-height:20px;
    opacity:1;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.animate-hide.ng-hide {
    left: -100%;
    opacity:0;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

**app-show.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp1", ["ngAnimate"]);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.myValue=false;
});
```

Please let me know what I am missing??

Comment: Are you sure you should have only one dot in the `src` attribute? (`<script src="./app-show.js"></script>` vs `<script src="../app-show.js"></script>`)

Comment: It has to be something that is reported in the console log.

Comment: Yes. All three files are in same folder.

Comment: console.log(myValue); to see if the value should indeed be hidden

Comment: does any error in console?

Comment: Shouldn't the classes be .ng-hide-add and .ng-hide-remove?

Comment: @rpadovani there would be only one dot. Because these files are in same folder. I tried with double dot but it gives 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the version of angular that you are using. In the example you provided the version is angular 1.2.20 whereas you are using 1.2.0-rc.2

Upgrade your version angular and you should find the code works.

Comment: Thanks @Leo . I think ng-how animation does not work in 1.2.0-rc.2, but ng-switch animation works.